# Headset problem with Ubuntu

Tags: sound, headphones

I have connected my headphones to my computer using the proper port. When I play music, the headphones are having playback problems. The sound gets distorted often. When i checked the sound settings, I found that my default output device is constantly switching between `headphone output` and `analog output`. I believe this is what distorts the output.

Answer (score 0):

A problem in jack plug detection is sometimes reported (as [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=158991)).
The 2 solutions  suppose  you have an independant "speaker" setting in alsamixer (or no external speaker).

- you can try to disable " automute" in alsamixer :
  launch alsamixer in a maximized terminal, press <kbd>F6</kbd> to select main sound card, scroll thru faders with <kbd>right arrow</kbd> to   "automute" , change value with <kbd>m</kbd> or <kbd>up/down arrow</kbd> )
- Another way is disabling jack sensor using **hda-jack-retask** :

  1. Install alsa-tools and alsa-tools-gui  then
  2. Close all applications including alsamixer and probably pulseaudio  (`pulseaudio -k` should stop it, but if it auto relaunches, run successively these 3 commands in a terminal :
     `mkdir ~/.pulse

     echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf

     pulseaudio -k`
  3. run **hda-jack-retask**. Clic "advanced override" , locate "headphones" , clic "override" near it, and select "not present" in "jack detection" , then "apply now".
     *You must unmute master fader in alsamixer , as "apply now" mute it.*
- to enable pulseaudio again,  run in a terminal
  `echo autospawn=yes > ~/.pulse/client.conf`
  `pulseaudio -D`

[image]